# Заменить все элементы от начала и до наибольшего элемента вещественного двумерного массива 4х4 . Помогите. скинул не рабочий код

Tags: c++

```
int max = ary[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
        if (max < ary[i][j]) {
            max = ary[i][j];
            maxI = i;
            maxJ = j;
        }

    }
}

cout << endl;
cout << "MAX:" << "[" << maxI+1 << "][" << maxJ+1 << "]" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < maxI+1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < maxJ+1; j++) {
        ary[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не рабочий код"? Ошибка логическая, времени выполнения или компиляции?

Comment: Заменить на что? Что значит "от начала и до наибольшего"? Построчно, постолбцово? Будьте добры, если хотите, чтоб вам помогали, формулировать просьбу точно. Вы точно, как новичок, прочли вот это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Answer (score 1):

Придерживаясь вашему стилью так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {            
        ary[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < maxJ; ++i)
    ary[maxI][i] = 0;
```

Сначала нужно заменять значения всех строк до строки, где находится максимальное число, а потом все элементы этой строки до максимального элемента. Но, конечно есть и другие способы решения... Например, можно и так:

```
int* p = ary[0];
for (int i = 0; i < maxI * DIM2 + maxJ; ++i)
    p[i] = 0;
```

А на `C++` можно всю программу выполнить одной строчкой:

```
std::fill(ary[0], std::max_element( ary[0], ary[0] + DIM1 * DIM2), 0);
```